# How can I read and write files that contains <?= $this->config->item('some_string');?>

Tags: php, this, file-get-contents

I am working with PHP templates. 
file_get_contents() throws an error when reading files with php code.

This is for an Apache server, PHP 7.1

when reading this file "_form.php"

```
<?php
$x = $this->config->item('btn_class_save');
```

using PHP's file_get_contents()

```
$str = file_get_contents(asset_url('misc/_form.php'));
```

I expect it to be able to write $str into another file. However I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci3ia3\assets\misc_form.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci3ia3\assets\misc_form.php on line 2

Any workaround?
This is used in a simple file templating system.

Comment: Theres something more you are omitting in your question. The file_get_contents read the file as a string, it doesn't make any processing that could lead to the error you posted. Aren't you using "include" or "require" to import the _form.php file somewhere ?

Comment: When I moved the template file from my assets folder into my views folder it works. It is like $this is now accepted.